A question about Bartoszynski (Set Theory, On the structure of the real line): Small sets
I have a question about Theorem 4.1.3 in Set Theory, On the structure of the real line.
The theorem states that the following conditions are equivalent:
(1) $\mathcal{F}$ is measurable.
(2) $\mathcal{F}$ is small.
(3) There is a family $\{\mathcal{A}_n: n \in \omega\}$ such that
(a) $\mathcal{A}_n$ consists of finitely many finite subsets of $\omega \ \forall n  < \omega$,
(b) $\bigcup \mathcal{A}_n \cap \bigcup \mathcal{A}_m = \emptyset$ for $n \neq m$
(c) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(\{X \subset \omega: \exists a \in \mathcal{A}_n \ a \subset X \}) < \infty$ and
(d) $\forall X \in \mathcal{F} \ \exists {}^{\infty}n \in \omega \ \exists a \in \mathcal{A}_n \ a\subset X$.
I want to show that (3) implies (2). The author states that $\mathcal{F} \subset \{X \subset \omega: \exists  {}^{\infty}n \in \omega
\ \exists a \in \mathcal{A}_n \ a \subset X \}$ and thanks to (c) this set is small. I can understand this argumentation, but I'm a bit confused as the definition of a small set requires that the family of all $\mathcal{A}_n$'s has to be a partition of $\omega$. Do we know if the $\mathcal{A}_n$ 's cover all of $\omega$?
Thanks a lot for any help in advance!

It doesn't really matter whether $\langle \bigcup \mathcal{A}_n : n \in \omega \rangle$ covers $\omega$.
Enumerate all the elements that are not covered as $\langle k_n : n \in \omega \rangle$. Then simply define $$I_n = \bigcup \mathcal{A}_n \cup \{ k_n \}.$$ Let $J_n$ be the set of characteristic functions of the sets $a \subseteq I_n$, $a \in \mathcal{A}_n$. Now you can check that 1,2 and 3 of the definition of small are satisfied. Specifically the sum in 2 is $\leq$ than the sum in (c).
Finally it also doesn't matter that the $I_n$ don't form an interval partition since we can find a permutation $\pi$ of $\omega$ that transforms it into one and induces a measure preserving map on $2^\omega$.
